# How to get new items in a scrollable flexbox container to appear newest lowermost (Fiddle included)

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, flexbox

I'm trying to implement a basic instant messaging interface with flexbox, where an interaction field constitute a static footer, and new messages appear at the bottom of the content field and push existing messages upwards.

I'm having difficulty however, in finding an elegant solution to the challenge of making new elements appear the lowermost.

I've made a fiddle here to illustrate my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/jensmtg/1fob3mat/

The closest I've gotten is to solving this is by implementing a system to give new messages a negative and decreasing css `order` value as they appear, but I hope there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unshift` instead of `push`

```
this.message_stack.unshift('This is message #' + this.message_count);
```

**Fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/1fob3mat/1/